# Center bootstrap columns without stacking

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I am using bootstrap to create some col-sm-4 elements in Django for every item that is queried for in the backend. The default behavior in bootstrap is to float all elements to the left, but since I don't know how many elements will be queried for in the backend, 1, 2, 3, etc., I am finding it very difficult to find a way to center the columns. for example if I only got two items from my backend query, I would want a 2 column wide gap on each side so the two two elements are perfectly centered but on the same row, or if there is only 1 item, than there will be a 4 column wide gap on each side to center the element. I tried using this a couple other stack overflow questions similar to this one, but in those cases they want all the columns to be centered and stacked on top of each other so there is only one element per row. Is there a simple way to accomplish this ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/disalvo_webdev/pen/XJOBdK/ This seems to solve your problem but it looks complicated

Comment: Check this http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/JRNpJg (refresh codepen to see effect)